# Search for multiple words by prefix (trie data structure)

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, prefix, trie

How can I use a trie (or another data structure or algorithm) to efficiently search for multiple words by prefix?

For example: suppose this is my data set:

- Alice Jones
- Bob Smith
- Bobby Walker
- John Doe
- (10000 names in total)

A trie data structure allows me to efficiently retrieve all names starting with "**Bo**" (thus without iterating over all the names). But I also want to search on the *last name* by prefix, thus searching for "**Wa**" should find "Bobby Walker". And to complicate things: when the user searches for "**Bo Wa**" this should also find the same name. How can I implement this? Should I use a separate trie structure for each part of the name? (And how to combine the results)?

Background: I'm writing the search functionality for a big address book (10000+ names). I want to have a really fast autocomplete function that shows results while people are typing the first few letters of the first & last name. I already have a solution that uses a regex, but it needs to iterate over all names which is to slow.

Answer (score 3):

A very good data structure would be a [Burst Trie](http://www.lindstaedt.com.br/estruturas/bursttries.pdf)

There's a [Scala implementation](https://github.com/nbauernfeind/scala-burst-trie).

Answer (score 2):

You could try a second trie with the reversed string and a wildcard search:http://phpir.com/tries-and-wildcards/

Answer (score 1):

I think that a sorted array will also fit for your requirements, an array containing `Person` objects (they have a `firstName` and a `lastName` field). Let's say that you have a `prefix` and want to find all the values that fit your `prefix`. Simply run a binary search to find the first position (let's say is `firstIndex`) where your `prefix` appears on `firstName` and one more to find the last position (`lastIndex`). Now you can retrieve your values in `O(lastIndex - firstIndex)`. The same goes when you want to find them by `lastName`. When you have a `prefixFirstName` and a `prefixLastName` you can search for the interval where values match for `prefixFirstName` and then, on this interval, you can check for the values matching the `prefixLastName`. For a conclusion, when you have one or two prefixes you run 4 binary searches (around 17 iterations per search for 100k names) which is fast enough and you can retrieve them in linear time. Even if it isn't the fastest solution, I suggested it since it's easy to understand and easy to code.